# debounce request on button click with angular

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I'm finding it hard to implement debounce on an HTTP request with Rxjs once a button is clicked. What I'm trying to achieve is when the button is click, it should wait for x seconds before the post is been made to the server.

```
btnClick() {
    this.loader = true;
    let send = "";
    send = this.checkForm.username.value;
    this.checkService
      .validate(send)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.loader = false)))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like calling a subject from the button click event handler to insert some debounce time, and then switchMap the post call

```js
    btnClicked$: Subject <string> = new Subject<string>();

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.btnClicked$.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap((send) => this.checkService.validate(send).pipe(
          finalize(() => (this.loader = false)))),
        take(1)
      ).subscribe()
    }

    btnClick(): void {
      this.btnClicked$.next(this.checkForm.username.value);
    }
```